# How to display the image preview when its uploaded

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

What I want is, when I upload the image from the FileUpload tag as soon as it displays the name of the image, in the image box below it, shows the preview of the image which is being uploaded.

The tag for file upload

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" width="280px" />
```

Tag for the image

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="221px" Width="212px" />
```

The code behind is

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
        if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
            string name = "~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            Image1.ImageUrl = name;
        }
```

The "Images" folder is on the host machine. The image is uploaded by the user. And on the same page(form) the preview of the image should be displayed.

Comment: What problem are you having? Is it not showing the image or anything else?

Comment: Ya! it's not showing the image automatically. I had to add an extra event for this. Like a button when pressed the preview of uploaded file will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

just use this code it is working in my project.

`

```
   if (uploadfilee.HasFile)
   {
        string str = uploadfilee.FileName;

        uploadfilee.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/" + str);
        string path = str.ToString();
        image1.Imageurl = path;
   }
```

`